# Nested loop in R - Error

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I have used a table (23 rows) where I extracted 2 columns (called them x and y) and named z=x-y and w=x-y. I also have a column called "type" which has 2 variables, "buy" or "sell".

I have an "ifelse" statement which states: If (type=="buy", z, w)

So, if i=1, type=buy, i want R to return z[[1]], i.e. the 1st answer from i=1 (not 23 answers for i=1). However, when I wrote down the loop, it returns 23 results for each "i".  (i.e. for i=1, it returns 23 results for i=1). I have tried using the [[i]] brackets but still no result.

```
for(i in 1:23)
{
  z[i]=y[i]-x[i]
  w[i]=x[i]-y[i]
  ifelse(type[i]=="buy", z[i], w[i])
}
```

Code without the for loop:

```
z=y-x #buy
w=x-y #sell
ifelse(type=="buy",z, w)
```

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand why the second version is not what you want. Also, I don't see any `if` statement in your code, only an `ifelse` statement. Or any nested loop?

Comment: Welcome to you. Please give a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example , https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dash2 because it returns 23x23 answers. I want the code to return the 1st result for i=1, the 2nd for i=2 and so forth. By nested, I mean the vectors are nested so if i do z[1] it will return the 1st 23 results. If i type z[[1] still the same

Comment: OK. Edit the question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ifelse` is vectorized.  You need to use

```
if(type[i] == buy) z[i] else w[i]
```

instead of ifelse within the for loop.  That said, the 2nd version is going to be much faster and cleaner in R.  I would strongly recommend you  use the vectorized method.